Error in output if column cell is empty or null in Power BI
While extracting a pattern from a text column 'Column1' into another column 'Release' in Power BI, I am getting an error if the column 'Column1' has an empty or null value. I have below code which works for non empty values but gives error if 'column1' cell is empty or null. I would like to skip the empty and null column values. How to fix this?
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\aditya\Documents\Test.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Sheet1_Sheet,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}}),
    #"Added Release" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Release", each let a = List.Transform(Text.Split([Column1], ";"), each Text.Trim(_)),
    b = List.Select(a, each Text.StartsWith(_,"R") and Value.Is(Value.FromText(Text.At(_, 1)), type number))
    in b{0}?)
    in
    #"Added Release"



Do you need to keep the rows where Column1 is null? if not, you can just filter out rows with Column1 = null. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-data-power-query-b5610630-f5bf-4ba4-9217-a628f9b89353

Filter is not possible as there are other reports based on the rows with empty values

each try ... 1)) otherwise null

It is failing on the Text.Split function in the #"Added Release" step.
Convert the null into "" so it won't fail on the Text.Split function:
a = List.Transform(Text.Split([Column1]??"", ";"), each Text.Trim(_)),


This M code really looks like C# more than I imagine !! I didn't know  nullable ?? works in M too!

@rachel In M it is just called the Coalesce operator.

I need to lookup that word. The nomenclature makes sense, now that I know what it means

Then you need to add null check:
let
  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name = "Table1"]}[Content],
  FilterList = (splits as list)=>
    let 
      b = List.Select(splits, each Text.StartsWith(_,"R") and Value.Is(Value.FromText(Text.At(_, 1)), type number))
    in 
      if List.Count(b) = 0  then "" else b{0},
  AddRelease = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Release", each if [Column1] = null then "" else FilterList(Text.Split([Column1],";")))
in
  AddRelease


